# plot the data of different columns using seaborn

Tags: dataframe, seaborn

I am trying to get a plot for every column in a dataframe based on two other columns in the same dataframe using seaborn.

Assuming that we have a dataframe with the following columns (X, Y, N1, N2, N2 ....). How can I get a plot for N1, N2, ... with two axes X and Y for all N's plots?

Answer (score 1):

**This may help you!**

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charles', 'David'],
        'y': [10, 20, 15, 25],
        'N1': [40000, 24000, 31000, 20000], 
        'N2': [6000, 4000, 3000, 2000]})

for col in data.iloc[:, 2:].columns:
    plt.figure()
    sns.stripplot(x='X', y='y', data=data, hue=col)
```